# How to use Pytorch to create a custom EfficientNet with the last layer written correctly

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, classification, conv-neural-network

I have a classification problem to predict 8 classes for example, I am using `EfficientNetB3` in pytorch from [here](https://github.com/rwightman/gen-efficientnet-pytorch/tree/master/geffnet). However, I got confused on whether my custom class is correctly written. I think I want to strip the last layer of the pre-trained model to suit the 8 outputs right? Did I do it correctly? Because when I print `y_preds = model(images)` in my `DataLoader`, it seems to give me `1536` predictions. Is this an expected behavior?

```
!pip install geffnet 
import geffnet

class EfficientNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config
        self.model = geffnet.create_model(config.effnet, pretrained=True)
        n_features = self.model.classifier.in_features
        # does the name fc matter?
        self.fc = nn.Linear(n_features, config.num_classes)
        self.model.classifier = nn.Identity()
        
    def extract(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.extract(x).squeeze(-1).squeeze(-1)
        return x
    
model = EfficientNet(config=config)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.cuda()
```

Sample code for printing `y_pred`:

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

```
for step, (images, labels) in enumerate(sample_loader):
    images = images.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(device)
    batch_size = images.shape[0]        
    y_preds = model(images)
    print('The predictions of the 4 images is as follows\n', y_preds)
    break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not even using `self.fc` in forward pass.

Either just introduce it as:

```
def forward(self, x):
    ....
    x = extract(x)...
    x = fc(x)
    return x
```

Or you can simply replace the layer named classifier (this way you don't need Identity layer):

```
self.model.classifier = nn.Linear(n_features, config.num_classes)
```

Also, here `config.num_classes` should be 8.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, one more question if I may, why do we need to `self.extract(x).squeeze(-1).squeeze(-1)` in the `forward` pass, why can't we just say:  `x = self.model(x)` and remove the `extract` method?

Comment: [torch.squeeze](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html) removes extra dimension of 1, you don't need it here. you can directly call self.model(x). I don't know why you were using it in first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, appreciate it. When would you want to use squeeze tho? As I saw some people doing it.

Comment: Sometimes, you may get extra dimension such as (1, 1, 3, 224, 224), to make it compatible with other operations that may work with only 4 dimensions, you can use squeeze. You'd also likely use `unsqeeze()` e.g. before feeding a single image tensor of size (3, 224, 224) to model such that its size becomes (1, 3, 224, 224) since pytorch requires shape as [N,C,H,W], where N is batch_size.

Comment: Crystal clear explanation. I would upvote you twice if I could.